# use md5 hashed guid as app login and REST interface

Tags: php, session-management, rest

We are planning to use a md5 hash of a user guid to confirm access to a GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE rest - api. All communication is over a secured https channel. The REST api is programmed to resist XSS and obviously injection problems (but programmed is just the thing). We would require a successful logon on the current session and session_regenerate_id() after logoff. Users would use it with the same md5/guid for an extended amount of time though.

The app is allowed to logon using a fixed md5-ed guid (by using a qr).

We make users aware of the sensitivity of the qr code and log all interactions with the api with the user id.

Is this scenario secure enough (we're not a bank) is there anything we can do to make this more secure?

Comment: Using md5(guid) is actually worse than sending the guid itself. It's unclear why you're not just using the guid, API keys or a server side session.

Comment: One reason a guid can easily be guessed if one already is known. GUID are not random strings but contain host, time etc. So I fail to see why an MD5 is worse. Please explain.

Comment: So you're saying the guids you're using are not sufficiently complex and can be enumerated? md5 won't solve that. If the md5 hash is ever mapped back to the source data then I can still "guess guids" I just need to add an extra step. However, md5 is vulnerable to hash collisions, key length extensions and in some cases type juggling which can allow me to "guess" valid keys without knowing the source string. However API keys or sessions should not have these issues. This feels like an XY problem and you might benefit from taking a step back and reassessing what problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it sounds like you're using a hash of a user ID as a credential.  That's not particularly secure, because if the user ID ever leaks, then the credential is immediately known.  It also prevents rotation of credentials, which you'd want to do in case the credential ever leaks as well.

And finally, it uses MD5, which is completely insecure and shouldn't be used anymore.  If you need a hash algorithm and don't know what to use, SHA-256 is the best choice, but in most cases, any hash of 256 bits or longer from SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2 is fine.  BLAKE2b also has the nice property of being faster than MD5 as well as cryptographically secure (which MD5 is not).

What would be better is to create a random credential with 128 bits or more from a cryptographically secure random number generator.  Then, you can prefix it with a fixed prefix to identify it as a credential (so it can be detected by credential scanners).  Something like `foo_8GfXueC2mapk3c0j0cNv9Q` would be an example.

You'd use that as the credential to log in, and you could store it in the database hashed with SHA-256 and associated with a particular user.  When the user uses a QR code or a token to log in, you hash it with SHA-256 and look it up in the database, and if it matches, you can identify the user.  If the credential needs to be revoked, you just delete the token from the database and issue a new one.  You can expire them if you need to in the future.

Note that storing passwords with a simple hash is not secure, but passwords do not typically contain 128 bits or more of entropy, which is why they need special hashing.  If you have sufficient entropy and are using a CSPRNG, then a simple hash isn't a problem.